# Php find and replace application

Tags: php, validation, post, get

I have started learning PHP recently. This is a find and replace application I made. It is working as it should but I am not sure if this is a good code. I've used Isset and empty functions a lot of times. Can I do that? or is there a better way ?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['find']) && isset($_POST['replace']) && !empty($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['find']) && !empty($_POST['replace']))

{
   $text=$_POST['text'];
   $find=$_POST['find'];
   $replace= $_POST['replace'];        
   $input= str_replace ($find, $replace, $_POST['text'] );

}

elseif(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['find']) && isset($_POST['replace']) && empty($text) && empty($find) && empty($replace))

 {
   echo 'enter you text';    
 }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not getting any error. The application is working absolutely fine.  Just want to know if its a common practice to use isset and empty functions like that so many times and if it is not going to make the application slow.

Comment: Okey. Not its not slow down you site. So don't be worried about it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question: I've used Isset and empty functions a lot of times. Can I do that? or is there a better way ?
Yes you can use isset in this way. The alternative command is 'empty' (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
You will find this checks are almost mandatory to prevent a poor user experience which always (in my opinion) trumps if it saves a few micro-seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this will be more efficient :

```
//$someString is NOT defined
//$someString = null;
if (empty($someString)) {
    // the condition passes without a warning
}

if ($someString == null) {
    // the condition passes WITH a warning
}

if (!isset($someString) || $someString == null) {
    // the condition passes without a warning

    // this conditional is a suitable replacement for empty() when
    // dealing with strings
}
```